# Deleting core data object based on MKAnnotion

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mkannotation

I'm storing and loading annotations onto a map based on coredata.

I'm not sure how to go about tapping on an annotation and deleting the coredata for that pin.

Unlike in a tableview, there's no real indexPath to delete from my fetched objects array. The only way I can think of keeping track of my annotations on the screen would be to give them all a tag and line that up with my fetched results array, but I feel like there has to be a better way.

I know how to implement tapping on a pin, but once I have that pin selected how do I tie that up with the coredata object it was created from?

```
func loadPins(){
        let pinRequest : NSFetchRequest<Pin> = Pin.fetchRequest()
        do {
           pins = try managedObjectContext.fetch(pinRequest)
        } catch {
           print("There was en error fetching pins")
        }
        for pin in pins {
            let lat = pin.latitude
            let lon = pin.longitude
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            createAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
        }
    }



func createAnnotation(coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "henlo"
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to create a class that conforms to MKAnnotation that holds the reference to your core data object (NSManagedObjectID).  When you select the pin you will have access to this object and therefore the core data object ID which you can use like so to get hold of the object and delete it.

`[managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:nil];`

`final class MapViewAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

```
let NSManagedObjectID: objectID
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let title: String?
let subtitle: String?

init(objectID: NSManagedObjectID, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?=nil, subtitle: String?=nil ) {
    self.objectID = objectID
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
}
```

}
`

Comment: I didn't even know ObjectID's were a thing. This is perfect, thank you!